# What is the difference between applying, running and calling of celery task?

Tags: python, celery

What is the difference between `mytask.apply()`, `mytask.run()` and `mytask()`? Which way is preferable?

Answer (score 15):

You can find all of this in the celery package in `celery/app/task.py`, or in the documentation http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html

To elaborate in my own investigation:

- **run** is the immediate (local blocking) form of `delay` with the same limitations (arguments get passed, however no access to other execution options), and is similar to calling. it will immediately return e.g. in case of an exception, so the call is fully blocking, and just like calling a function.

```py
tasks.my_task.run(foo='bar')
```

my_task() is the documented one, and acts like `run`. (in fact, `Task.__call__` executes `self.run(*args, **kwargs)`); It should be probably preferred over run(), as it does other things as well.

```py
tasks.my_task(foo='bar')
```

**so between mytask.run() and mytask() i would choose mytask(), except if i know i want run instead. If it would be rewritten, as true celery worker function, both would be rewritten as delay()**

- **apply** is the form which uses a syntax akin to apply_async. so your arguments are added as args/kwargs keywords:

```py
tasks.my_task.apply(kwargs={'foo': 'bar'})
```

it is also the function called by apply_async if it is set to always_eager.
A side effect is, that exceptions would continue execution, just as apply_async would, if it is not set to always_eager or gets the throw keyword set.

**when i want to have a syntax which later gets changed into apply_async, i would prefer apply - generally i would prefer apply personally.**

Comment: actually shortly after investigating this, i also found http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html which does document all functions mentioned. it does not change my explanation, but it is documented.

Answer (score 4):

In my understanding:

- `apply`: is to call task and execute locally
- `run`:   never seen before
- `mytask()`: just like call func

If you want to send message and execute remote,you should use `apply_async` or `delay`, referring [call_task](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#basics).